# Is there a cross platform (web, flutter) firestore API?

Tags: dart, flutter, angular-dart

I'm designing a cross platform app, and I'm attempting to code-share the underlying services and models to both apps. However, it appears there are specific apis for each platform (AngularDart and Flutter), making code sharing very hard, especially since both apis have a very different API and one that cannot be dependency injected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to create your own abstraction between these two.

Flutter forwards to the JAVA implementation on Android and ObjectC (or Swift - not sure) on iOS, and the Dart Web application forwards to the JavaScript implementation. Unfortunately the Flutter and Web implementations don't share common base classes, so you're on your own.
It shouldn't be too difficult though.

Comment: For business logic it is possible to share between Angular and Flutter. Something with Streams... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLHln7wHgPE&index=13&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIIJr3vjxggY7yGcGO7i9BK5

Comment: Yes, you can share business logic. You need some abstraction for platform specific code like Flutter, IO, and Web